# 503 Service Unable: No registered leader was found after waiting for 4000 ms

Tags: csv, post, solr, import, lucene

I've recently started using solr. I'm using the latest Solr v6.1.0. I followed the [quick start](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html) tutorial to get a feel of it. Being, a windows user I had to resort to the other way of importing my .csv data using [Post tool for Windows](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Post+Tool#PostTool-Windows)

I am primarily interested in seeing how Solr can handle and search large data sets like the one I have. It is a 522 MB `my_db.csv` file which properly formatted (ran various python scripts to check that).

I started the solr cloud by the usual procedure. Then, I imported a part of this dataset (to be specfic, 29 lines of `my_db.csv`) to see if it works.

**Shell:**

```
C:\Users\MAC\Downloads\solr-6.1.0\solr-6.1.0>java -Dc=gettingstarted -Ddata=files -Dauto=yes -jar example\exampledocs\post.jar example\exampledocs\29lines.csv
```

**Result was:**

```
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update...
Entering auto mode. File endings considered are xml,json,jsonl,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
POSTing file 29lines.csv (text/csv) to [base]
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update...
Time spent: 0:01:28.106
```

Fortunately, it worked perfectly and I was able to use the default velocity search wrapper that they provide by going to http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted_shard2_replica1/browse . It had all my data stored so far. 29 rows to be precise.

Now, I wanted to see if the whole 522 MB of data would be imported for which I used the same command (just replaced the .csv file, ofcourse) and then I run it. I did expect it to take a while, and after nearly 10 minutes it had inserted around *32,674* out of *1,300,000* and then it threw out this error.

**Result was:**

```
SimplePostTool version 5.0.0
Posting files to [base] url http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update...
Entering auto mode. File endings considered are xml,json,jsonl,csv,pdf,doc,docx,ppt,pptx,xls,xlsx,odt,odp,ods,ott,otp,ots,rtf,htm,html,txt,log
POSTing file omdbFull.csv (text/csv) to [base]
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #503 (Service Unavailable) for url: http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">503</int><int name="QTime">128191</int></lst><lst name="error"><lst name="metadata"><str name="error-cla
ss">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str><str name="root-error-class">org.apache.solr.common.SolrException</str></lst><str name="msg">No register
ed leader was found after waiting for 4000ms , collection: gettingstarted slice: shard2</str><int name="code">503</int></lst>
</response>
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://localhost:89
83/solr/gettingstarted/update
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update...
Time spent: 0:08:36.342
```

**Summary**

This was strange. I wasn't exaclty sure why this had happened. Is it perhaps that I have to change some kind of a "timeout" parameter for it to commit in? Unfortunately I wasn't able to see any such option for the windows post tool.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. The problem wasn't that the file was huge. Which in my case was around 500 MB csv. I'm sure it will go through for even larger files.

The thing is, I think Solr has some kind of auto recognizing the kind of values are input in an index. For instance, my CSV had a column with "Years" like "2015","2014","1970"... etc. but when this column also had improper years which I didn't know, like "2014-2015", "1980-1988".

Solr would stop and throw out an exception because this was not a year but an year range. It wasn't expecting a value of this sort.

**Summary**

To fix the problem, I simply filtered out the faulty year rows and volla! it processed my 500 MB csv in around 15 minutes. After thatm I had a good nice database ready to be searched!